# Display Dynamic Content using a conditional statement

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I need a solution for a php based [website](http://unique-tec.com). I have a testimonial in homepage page in which the content should be dynamically displayed from the back-end. and also i need a conditional statement for it. If the testimonial is approved from back-end, then display the content in homepage, if not , do not show.

[image: Images]

Html mainpage Codes

```
     <aside id="home-marketing-testimonials">
           <span class="section_title"><h6 style="color:#fff200; font-weight:bold;">Our Students Say it Best</h6></span>
           <div class="testimonials" style="text-align:justify;">
              <div class="testimonial">
                 <blockquote style="color:#fff;">
                   <?php
           $nsql = mysql_query("select * from testimonials order by id desc limit 0,1");
           while($nrow = mysql_fetch_array($nsql))
           {
                ?>

               <?php echo $nrow[5]; ?></a></strong>
                  <?php 
                  $nrowlen = strlen($nrow[1]);
                  if($nrowlen > 220)
                  {
                        echo substr($nrow[1],0,220)."...";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        echo "<div style='font-size:12px;color:yellow; margin-top:10px;'>".$nrow[1]."</div>";
                  }
                  ?>
                 </blockquote>
                   <?php
           }
           ?>
                 <strong class="client_identity" style="color:#fff; float:left;"><a class="test_author" href="students-testimonials.php"></a></strong>
              </div>


           </div>

        </aside>
```

Backend testimonial code:

```
<div class="content_display">
        <div class="widgetcontent bordered">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                <!--<div align="right"><a href="add_pages.php" style="margin-bottom: 10px; color:#fff;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a></div>-->
        <table class="table table-bordered"  width="100%">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                    <col class="con0" />
                    <col class="con1" />
                </colgroup>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th width="10%">S.No</th>
                        <th width="20%">Name</th>
                        <th width="20%">Student ID</th>
                        <th width="20%">Email</th>
                        <th width="10%">Status</th>
                        <th width="20%">Options</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 <?php 
                $i=1;
                $sql=mysql_query("select * from testimonials order by id desc");

                while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $res['name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $res['stuid']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $res['email']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php 
                        if($res['cstatus']=="0")
                        {
                            echo "Disapproved";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Approved";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <a href="view_testimonial.php?id=<?php echo $res['id']; ?>">View</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <?php 
                        if($res['cstatus']=="0")
                        {
                            echo '<a href="approve.php?id='.$res['id'].'">Approve</a>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<a href="disapprove.php?id='.$res['id'].'">Disapprove</a>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="ConfirmChoice(<?php echo $res['id']; ?>);">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php
               $i++; }?></tbody></table></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the front end code with the mysql line changed, the loop started from the correct place, and the if/else statement corrected...

```
<aside id="home-marketing-testimonials">
       <span class="section_title"><h6 style="color:#fff200; font-weight:bold;">Our Students Say it Best</h6></span>
       <div class="testimonials" style="text-align:justify;">
       <?php
           $nsql = mysql_query("select * from testimonials where cstatus=1 order by id desc limit 3");
           while($nrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($nsql)) {
               //start testimonial div and blockquote
               echo "<div class='testimonial'><blockquote style='color:#fff;'>";

               //shorten quote if too long
               $nrowlen = strlen($nrow['comments']);
               if ($nrowlen > 220) $nrow['comments']=substr($nrow['comments'],0,220)."...";

               //insert quote and end blockquote
               echo "<div style='font-size:12px;color:yellow; margin-top:10px;'>".$nrow['comments']."</div></blockquote>";

               //student identity (start and end)
               echo "<strong class='client_identity' style='color:#fff; float:left;'><a class='test_author' href='students-testimonials.php'>".$nrow['name']."</a></strong>";

               //end testimonial div
               echo "</div>";
           }
       ?>               
       </div>
</aside>
```

I also used mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array so that I could use the column names ($nrow['name']) instead of the column id numbers ($nrow[1])

Also notice I'm using LIMIT 3 here.  It looks like on your site you only pull three quotes.  If this can ever be a different number, just change the number 3.

Comment: Did u see my webpage, if i have three testimonials, will it it change , or should i make sum changes in the html page, if there is so. please suggest

Comment: Right now you have LIMIT 0,1 at the end, which means it's only going to show one.  You can get rid of the LIMIT 0,1 part and it will get however many exist that match cstatus=1

Comment: I needed the testimonials to change .. but now the 1st testimoials is only showing

Comment: i don't want everything to be shown , it should change , there is a tesitmonial scroller run by .js file. thats shows one at a time.  Please see my html webpage and my above code. and please tell me if i need to twick